# Pipeline failed to Add the App registration Client secret password to Azure Key vault secret

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have an automated script which reads the azure App Reg secrets expiry and creates a new secret based on the counter days.
In the same PowerShell file from the pipeline, I am trying to add the new secret generated from the script to respective key vault.

I am able to create and add the secret to KV locally using PowerShell ISE with the same SP authentication.

From the Devops pipeline, I am able to create the client secret but when trying to add the new client secret to key vault secret, I am getting below error:

> ##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
> Code: Forbidden
> Message: Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
> Client address: 12.34.56.189
> Caller: appid=xxx;oid=abcded-8855-3rfg-56gt-fdvtr;iss=https://sts.windows.net/abcded-8855-3rfg-56gt-fdvtr/
> Vault: test-kv;location=eastus2

I am using below command to add the client secret to the KV.

```
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $newpass
```

I am using a Service principal to authenticate/login to Azure AD and the same SP has Application administration permissions. The SP has almost all the permissions to the key vault as well.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/5zjZrGK.png)?

Comment: Yes I am able to add the secret value to key vault secret locally from PS ISE. but from the pipeline, it is failed with 'Forbidden' error.

Comment: Could you provide the pipeline command that you are using?

Comment: For Auth, ` #Connect Azure Account
az login --service-principal -u $SPNCLIENTID -p $SPNSECRET --tenant $ADTENANT --allow-no-subscriptions


Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -force

#Get AAD token from previous Az login.
$aadToken = az account get-access-token --resource-type aad-graph | ConvertFrom-Json

#Get Graph token using previous Az login
$graphToken = az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph | ConvertFrom-Json

#Connect Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken.accessToken -AccountId $SPNCLIENTID -TenantId $ADTENANT -MsAccessToken $graphToken.accessToken`

Comment: Using below command to copy the secret to KV: Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $newpass    ($newpass has the new secret which has been generated from the previous block of creating client secret script)

Comment: Could you try `Connect-AzAccount -TenantId TenantID -ApplicationId AppID -CertificateThumbprint XXX` and then add secret to Key Vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, it indicates the DevOps agent client is not using the trusted IP.

> ##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' Code: Forbidden Message: Client address is not authorized and caller is not
> a trusted service. Client address: 12.34.56.189 Caller:
> appid=xxx;oid=abcded-8855-3rfg-56gt-fdvtr;iss=https://sts.windows.net/abcded-8855-3rfg-56gt-fdvtr/
> Vault: test-kv;location=eastus2

Please check your Azure Key Vault Networking Setting:

[image]

If you are using Self-hosted agent, make sure you have added the IP of your Self-hosted agent into Key Vault Firewall whitelist.

If you are using Microsoft-hosted agent, you could follow this official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) and add all the IP ranges from [weekly file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) in your region to the Key Vault Firewall whitelist.

[image]